# How to search log within specific range of date and time in elasticsearch using java api

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am newbie to elasticsearch and its java api. I did try to write hello world java program to search some string in which i use matchQuery function with QueryBuilder and it works fine. The code is given below.

Code:

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchType;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders;



public class ElasticSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SearchResponse response1=null;
        Client client = new TransportClient()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("192.168.1.142", 9301));

         try{

           //**** SEARCH *****//
           response1 = client.prepareSearch("logstash-2015.03.03")
                   .setTypes("syslog")
                   .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                   .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("log_message", "Scanning directory or file : smb://test\":***@\"localhost/SambaShareIn"))
                   .setExplain(true)
                   .execute()
                   .actionGet();



                System.out.println("*****************Hits***************"+response1.getHits().getTotalHits());

           SearchHit[] searchHitArray = response1.getHits().getHits();
           SearchHit searchHit = searchHitArray[0];
           System.out.println("#########"+searchHit.getSourceAsString());
           System.out.println("*****************Hits***************"+response1.getHits().getHits());

         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
             client.close();

        if (response1.getHits().getTotalHits()>0) {
           System.out.println("********Test Case Passed*******");
        } else {

           System.out.println("********Test Case not Passed*******");
           int a=10/0;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*****************Hits***************104
#########{"message":"TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-05 18:06:14,458] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener} -  Scanning directory or file : smb://test\":***@\"localhost/SambaShareIn {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener}","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2015-03-03T06:34:05.879Z","type":"syslog","host":"ubuntu","path":"/home/abc/Documents/wso2esb-4.8.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log","tenant_id":"0","server_type":"ESB","timestamp":"2015-02-05 18:06:14,458","level":"DEBUG","java_class":"org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener","log_message":"Scanning directory or file : smb://test\":***@\"localhost/SambaShareIn {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener}"}
*****************Hits***************[Lorg.elasticsearch.search.internal.InternalSearchHit;@2eaae131
********Test Case Passed*******
```

but now i want to find result that are logged within a specific range of date and time. I am using timestamp range but i am getting exception. The code and exception is given below.

Code:

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchType;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders;



public class ElasticSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SearchResponse response1=null;
        Client client = new TransportClient()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("192.168.1.142", 9301));

         try{

           //**** SEARCH *****//
           response1 = client.prepareSearch("logstash-2015.03.03")
                   .setTypes("syslog")
                   .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                   .setQuery("range : {timestamp : {gt : now-24h}}")
                   .setExplain(true)
                   .execute()
                   .actionGet();


           //System.out.println(response1);
                System.out.println("*****************Hits***************"+response1.getHits().getTotalHits());

           SearchHit[] searchHitArray = response1.getHits().getHits();
           SearchHit searchHit = searchHitArray[0];
           System.out.println("#########"+searchHit.getSourceAsString());
           System.out.println("*****************Hits***************"+response1.getHits().getHits());

         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
             client.close();

        if (response1.getHits().getTotalHits()>0) {
           System.out.println("********Test Case Passed*******");
        } else {

           System.out.println("********Test Case not Passed*******");
           int a=10/0;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[ewJbD-euTBybuTt1-vgGgQ][logstash-2015.03.03][0]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.03.03][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query_binary":"cmFuZ2UgOiB7dGltZXN0YW1wIDoge2d0IDogbm93LTI0aH19","explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[logstash-2015.03.03] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'range': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@6e98e93a; line: 1, column: 7]]; }{[ewJbD-euTBybuTt1-vgGgQ][logstash-2015.03.03][1]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.03.03][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query_binary":"cmFuZ2UgOiB7dGltZXN0YW1wIDoge2d0IDogbm93LTI0aH19","explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[logstash-2015.03.03] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'range': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@5a4f889; line: 1, column: 7]]; }{[ewJbD-euTBybuTt1-vgGgQ][logstash-2015.03.03][2]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.03.03][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query_binary":"cmFuZ2UgOiB7dGltZXN0YW1wIDoge2d0IDogbm93LTI0aH19","explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[logstash-2015.03.03] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'range': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@6e98e93a; line: 1, column: 7]]; }{[ewJbD-euTBybuTt1-vgGgQ][logstash-2015.03.03][3]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.03.03][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query_binary":"cmFuZ2UgOiB7dGltZXN0YW1wIDoge2d0IDogbm93LTI0aH19","explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[logstash-2015.03.03] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'range': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@78f8178f; line: 1, column: 7]]; }{[ewJbD-euTBybuTt1-vgGgQ][logstash-2015.03.03][4]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.03.03][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query_binary":"cmFuZ2UgOiB7dGltZXN0YW1wIDoge2d0IDogbm93LTI0aH19","explain":true}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[logstash-2015.03.03] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token 'range': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@3e11473; line: 1, column: 7]]; }
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:233)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:179)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:565)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at nl.weIntegrtae.Search.ElasticSearch.main(ElasticSearch.java:78)
```

Can any body help me to find result in a specific range of date and time.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query is wrong .. Either use json query or pure java query. You can see it on elastic search query dsl for date range query.
It has both queries in json and in java also.
For making json queries u can use sense plugin for elastic search.
Like this 
Json query--

```
{
"range" : {
    "timestamp" : {
        "gte": "now-24"
    }
}
```

}

Or in java make q querybuilder and set it into setQuery method

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
                .rangeQuery("timestamp")
                .from("now-24")
                .to("now");
```

Comment: Is timestamp your field or elasticsearch provided?? It it's elastic search provided then it must me _timestamp. Can u also check if u really have data for last 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks @Satya Nand kanodia for help. Now it makes clear sense for me, but when i run it does not retrieve result even node is created in elastic search. I have checked the node by installing its head plug-in. Can you please guide a bit for it?

Comment: No it is mine. I have created it.

Comment: Do you have data for last 24 hours??

Comment: Can you also post the response you got when you queried.

Comment: Output: *****************Hits***************0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at nl.abc.Search.ElasticSearch.main(ElasticSearch.java:66)
********Test Case not Passed*******

Comment: can you confirm that you have data for last 24 hours which is you are trying to get. you are getting exception because you are getting 0 hits and in this line 
    SearchHit searchHit = searchHitArray[0];
you are trying to get 0 index.
you should use foreach loop for such kind of cases to retirve all data like 

    for(SearchHit searchHit:searchHitArray)